# Entity Framework Join Table not populating

Tags: entity-framework

**I have two tables: (1)Student and (2) Course, I also have a join table called (3)StudentCourse.
The relevant data:**

```
public class Student
{
  private ICollection<Course> _courses 
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public Student(){
   _courses = new Collection<Course>();
  }

  public ICollection<Course> Courses{
   get {return _courses;}
   set { _courses = value;}
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Course
{
  private ICollection<Student> _students 
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public Course(){
   _students = new Collection<Student>();
  }

  public ICollection<Student> Students{
   get {return _students;}
   set { _students = value;}
  }
}
```

---

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
            .HasMany<Student>(r => r.Students)
            .WithMany(u => u.Courses)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("StudentCourse");
                m.MapLeftKey("CourseId");
                m.MapRightKey("StudentId");
            });
    }
```

---

My context constructor has :  Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

When I seed my Course and Student tables via Migration, the StudentCourse table is not populating.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I failed to add the CourseCollection to Student class